# scala runtime reflect sometimes throws exception

Tags: scala, scala-compiler

```
object Reflects {

  def mirror() = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

  def caseFields(x: AnyRef) = {
    val instanceMirror = mirror().reflect(x)
    instanceMirror.symbol.typeSignature.members.collect {
      case m: MethodSymbol if (m.isCaseAccessor) => m.name.toString -> instanceMirror.reflectMethod(m).apply()
    }
  }

}
```

I define an object `Reflects`, when I invole `caseFields` method within other class

> Sometimes this method throws following exception

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list
at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.tail(List.scala:339) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.tail(List.scala:334) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.popPhase(SymbolTable.scala:172) ~[scala-reflect.jar:na]
```

And other strange exception.

What's wrong with this method

Comment: Your stack trace doesn't show where in your code the exception is being thrown. I will speculate that you aren't checking `members` size.

Comment: @pedrofurla Even if the members size is zero. this method should return empty Map. I think it is something related to scala-reflect

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace? Also, do you run this method in multiple threads?

Comment: @jilen Very true, silly me.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako I call that method in one or more akka actors.

Comment: @jilen See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.10.3 (and probably in 2.10.4, because it doesn't look like we're going to have time to backport the fix from 2.11.0-M7), runtime reflection isn't thread-safe: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/thread-safety.html. Your stack trace is one of the multitude of possible manifestations of the problem.

Bad news is that in 2.10.x there's no workaround for the thread-unsafety issue apart from putting all reflective operations in a synchronized block. Good news is that in 2.11.0 the problem should be gone.

Comment: So, if I put synchronized to the method, this issue should be fixed ?

Comment: As long as you don't do runtime reflection anywhere else in the program.

Comment: But there are a lot of third-party libraries, I don't know whether they will use runtime reflection, bad luck...

Comment: I'll try to get to backporting either in 2.10.4 or 2.10.5